# jQuery's delegate() method, index number of the current element?

Tags: jquery

Using jQuery's delegate() method, can I get the index number of the current element?

For example:

```
$('#tracks').delegate('.track-item', 'click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert($('.track-item').index(this));
});
```

Does anyone have an elegant solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should work perfectly fine. What's the problem?

Comment: Ahh, it does return when I run my code in jQuery fiddle. So it should be working. Must be something on my end. Cheers guys!

Answer (score 2):

What you have works, [you can see it in action here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/PGgp9/).

The alternative form is:

```
alert($(this).index('.track-item'));
```

[You can try that one here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/PGgp9/1/).